# FLUTTER: I want to record the stream of microphone and play it immediately

Tags: audio, dart, flutter, microphone

I want to do and application who take the stream of microphone and who play it directly in Flutter, who can help me, i've find nothing on internet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a few changes it's working that way, please use this plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream

Import this on your pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  sound_stream: ^0.2.0
```

And use this sample code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:sound_stream/sound_stream.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  RecorderStream _recorder = RecorderStream();
  PlayerStream _player = PlayerStream();

  List<Uint8List> _micChunks = [];
  bool _isRecording = false;
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  StreamSubscription _recorderStatus;
  StreamSubscription _playerStatus;
  StreamSubscription _audioStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlugin();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _recorderStatus?.cancel();
    _playerStatus?.cancel();
    _audioStream?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlugin() async {
    _recorderStatus = _recorder.status.listen((status) {
      if (mounted)
        setState(() {
          _isRecording = status == SoundStreamStatus.Playing;
        });
    });

    _audioStream = _recorder.audioStream.listen((data) {
      if (_isPlaying) {
        _player.writeChunk(data);
      } else {
        _micChunks.add(data);
      }
    });

    _playerStatus = _player.status.listen((status) {
      if (mounted)
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = status == SoundStreamStatus.Playing;
        });
    });

    await Future.wait([
      _recorder.initialize(),
      _player.initialize(),
    ]);
  }

  void _play() async {
    await _player.start();

    if (_micChunks.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var chunk in _micChunks) {
        await _player.writeChunk(chunk);
      }
      _micChunks.clear();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 96.0,
              icon: Icon(_isRecording ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
              onPressed: _isRecording ? _recorder.stop : _recorder.start,
            ),
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 96.0,
              icon: Icon(_isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow),
              onPressed: _isPlaying ? _player.stop : _play,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for iOS there is this error: `Xcode's output:
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility51'`
   etc. Any idea WHY?

Answer (score 1):

The `flutter_sound`([github](https://github.com/Canardoux/flutter_sound) and [docs](https://flutter-sound.canardoux.xyz/readme.html)) library seems to have good tools for working with audio and streams.

There is even an [example page for streams](https://github.com/Canardoux/flutter_sound/blob/master/flutter_sound/example/lib/recordToStream/record_to_stream_example.dart) that shows exactly how to record to a stream and playback. You just need to add dependencies to your `pubspec.yaml` and necessary permissions to the platform permission files, then the linked example will stand alone as a page with both a recorder and player to demonstrate functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audio_recorder) library to record audio from microphone.

**Usage**
To use this plugin, add `audio_recorder` as a dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

**Android**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**iOS**

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Record audio for playback</string>
```

**Example**

```
// Import package
import 'package:audio_recorder/audio_recorder.dart';

// Check permissions before starting
bool hasPermissions = await AudioRecorder.hasPermissions;

// Get the state of the recorder
bool isRecording = await AudioRecorder.isRecording;

// Start recording
await AudioRecorder.start(path: _controller.text, audioOutputFormat: AudioOutputFormat.AAC);

// Stop recording
Recording recording = await AudioRecorder.stop();
print("Path : ${recording.path},  Format : ${recording.audioOutputFormat},  Duration : ${recording.duration},  Extension : ${recording.extension},");
```

Now all you need to do is play the recorded sound file.